# Cannot understand question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can anyone please help me understand the meaning of this question?

So let $f(x,y) = x^2y - 3xy^3 = z$
$P = (1,1,1)$

Equation of tangent plane at $P$:
$z = -x-8y+7$

Next the question says 'The unit normal vector at this same point oriented to make an acute angle with the positive $z$ axis is $__$i$+__$j$+__k$

I am not asking for the answer, just an explanation...

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of a plane, there is a unit normal vector, whose direction is oriented in the coefficients of the implicit definition of a plane:
$a*x+b*y+c*z = d$

The normal vector would therefore be: $\left<a,b,c\right>$ or a modification thereof (can't recall exactly).

From that, you have the normal vector, and just need to normalize it.
$norm(\left<a,b,c\right>)=\frac{\left<a,b,c\right>}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$